# Recommended way to "poll" a file descriptor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, epoll, udev

I see there's wrapper libraries for select(2) and poll(2), but they don't seem much used.

The epoll-based `System.Event` used [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Servers#Epoll-based_event_callbacks) has since been merged in as `GHC.Event` (though the `loop` function got put in to the private module `GHC.Event.Manager` and isn't exported, so apparently only `getSystemEventManager` is usable). `GHC.Event` says "This module should be considered GHC internal.", which has me wondering - is there some library that wraps that that I should be using, instead?

Some background on my use-case: I wanted to perform an action on a udev event (update a display when e.g. brightness changes). The example here is using the select(2) wrapper: https://github.com/pxqr/udev/blob/master/examples/monitor.hs#L36
I was hoping to use something more modern / better maintained and/or less dependencies.

Comment: Turns out there's `threadWaitRead` and `threadWaitWrite` in `Control.Concurrent` to block the current thread until a file descriptor is ready for reading / writing, without actually doing reading or writing.

Comment: Note that the GHC runtime automatically uses `poll` when Haskell threads (which might be run on a single OS thread) are stuck. The usual solution is to forget about `poll` and `forkIO` may green threads doing blocking I/O, and let the GHC runtime call `poll` for you. The functions you mention also help, if you do not want to read right now.